# Discriminant Analysis when assumptions are violated

Tags: r, classification

Is there a way to perform Discriminant Analysis when your data is not normally distributed and the covariance matrices are not equal?

Answer (score 0):

1. To be precise, discriminant analysis (linear and quadratic, see below) assumes that your data *within classes* are normally distributed, not overall.
2. Apart from linear discriminant analysis (LDA) that assumes equal covariance matrices, there is also quadratic discriminant analysis (QDA) that still assumes normality but allows covariance matrices to differ between classes.
3. Quite generally, having "assumptions" in statistics does *not* mean that methods can only be applied if the model holds (if this were the case, statistics could never be applied as "all models are wrong" - but some are useful). It only means that certain mathematical theory exists that makes sure that the method has one or more good characteristics in case the model holds. It does *not* mean that the method is necessarily bad if the model doesn't hold. Both LDA and QDA can also be applied to non-normal data. They may not be as good as alternatives there, but this depends on how precisely the assumption is violated and what alternatives you try. If the information in the data can be well summarised using means and covariance matrices, LDA and QDA may do quite well also for non-normal data, but this isn't always the case. You can use nonparametric techniques such as cross-validation to see how good a job any classification method does, and whether LDA/QDA work OK for your specific problem or rather not, regardless of normality.
4. Obviously there is a large array of alternative classification methods in case LDA/QDA don't do a good job, some of which I have occasionally also seen referred to as "discriminant analysis". For example there are a number of techniques referred to as "robust discriminant analysis" that can deal better with outliers and heavier distributional tails, while still representing classes by robust versions of means and covariance matrices.

Comment: I used the definition 8.5 from this [pdf](http://parker.ad.siu.edu/Olive/mch8.pdf)